# Granting a third-party access via api for AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oauth

How can I let another user access to my AWS S3 bucket without having to create an IAM role for it and sending the key/secret.
I want the third-party to decide the credentials for himself.

Is this even possible?

Basically I'm searching for something similar to OAuth for S3

Answer (score 4):

By default, Amazon S3 buckets are private.

Access to objects can be granted in several ways:

- A **Bucket Policy** can make a bucket, or part of a bucket, publicly accessible (not applicable for your use-case)
- The **Access Control List (ACL)** on an object can make it publicly accessible (not applicable for your use-case)
- **IAM Users** can be granted permissions on an Amazon S3 bucket (but IAM Users should only be used for your staff, not for application users)
- **IAM Roles** can be temporarily assumed, but first require authentication (more on this below)
- **Pre-Signed URLs** can be generated to provide time-limited access to Amazon S3 objects

For your use-case, the most applicable approach would be:

- Users **authenticate** to your application. This could use Amazon Cognito, or whatever authentication method you wish to use.
- When a user wishes to access a private object, your application determines whether they are **entitled to such access** (done via your own code).
- If they are permitted access, the application should generate a **pre-signed URL**. This URL can be included in tags like `<a>` and `<img>`.
- When the user accesses the URL, they will be able to access the object directly from Amazon S3.
- Once the **expiry time** passes, the pre-signed URL no longer works.

So, you are welcome to use OAuth or any other authentication method, but it is the responsibility of your application to determine whether they are entitled to access individual objects and, if so, generate and return the pre-signed URL. (It's just a couple of lines of code, no API calls required to generate it.)

See: [Share an Object with Others - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Amazon Cognito has the ability to issue credentials associated with an **IAM Role**, and users could then use these credentials to make API calls to AWS. However, it is generic role that would be shared by many users and is not a way to grant user-specific permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much! i will try this method and accept the solution when it workes out